# Using react-router-dom to create Breadcrumbs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am attempting to use the match parameter to create the Component name dynamically. I am currently building the Components and need to add the Breadcrumbs.  Using 'match' may not be the best way to do this. The BreadCrumbs Component is display each Component/Page name but Im trying to figure out how to show the hierarchy. Eg. Company > Sites > Site Dashboard > Site AccDetails.

Thanks.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import logo from './assets/img/svg/OrisecLogo.svg'
import "./assets/scss/mdb.scss"

import LoginHome from './LoginHome'
import CompanyDashboard from './Components/Company/CompanyDashboard'
import CompanyAccDetails from './Components/Company/CompanyAccDetails'
import SiteDashboard from './Components/Company/Sites/SiteDashboard'
import SiteAccDetails from './Components/Company/Sites/SiteAccDetails'
import Sites from './Components/Company/Sites/Sites';

const App = () => <div>

    <Router>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <img src={logo} className="orisec-logo" alt="Orisec logo" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6 header-login pr-5">
                <Link to="/Login">Log In <i className="fa fa-sign-in-alt"></i></Link>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to="/Login">Login</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/CompanyDashboard">Company Dashboard</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/CompanyAccDetails">Company Dashboard / Company Account Details</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/Sites">Sites</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/SiteDashboard">Site Dashboard</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/SiteAccDetails">Site Dashboard / Site Account Details</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr />
                    <Breadcrumbs />
                    <hr />
                    <Route path="/Login" component={LoginHome} />
                    <Route path="/CompanyDashboard" component={CompanyDashboard} />
                    <Route path="/CompanyAccDetails" component={CompanyAccDetails} />
                    <Route path="/Sites" component={Sites} />
                    <Route path="/SiteDashboard" component={SiteDashboard} />
                    <Route path="/SiteAccDetails" component={SiteAccDetails} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Router>;

  </div>

const Topics = ({ match }) =>

    <div>
        <div>
            <h2>Company Dashboard</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to={`${match.url}/CompanyAccDetails`}>Account Details</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={`${match.url}/Sites`}>Sites</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={`${match.url}/Engineers`}>Engineers</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

const Breadcrumbs = () => <Route path="*" render={props => {
    let parts = props.location.pathname.split("/");
    const place = parts[parts.length - 1];
    parts = parts.slice(1, parts.length - 1);
    return <p>{parts.map(crumb)}/{place}</p>
}} />

const crumb = (part, partIndex, parts) => {
    const path = ['', ...parts.slice(0, partIndex + 1)].join("/");
    return <Link key={path} to={path} >{part}</Link>
}

export default App
```

Comment: `match.params.topicId` how does this value correspond to a component?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate a React element directly from a string, you will have to maintain a mapping from strings to React Classes.

```
const Map = { "componentA" : ComponentA }

// render
<Map[match.params.topicId] />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a component for each case of `match.params.topicId` you can build a dictionary that maps the values of `topicId` to their respective component.

For example, if you have two possible values for `topicId` that are *topicId1* (associated to `TopicId1` component) and *topicId2* (associated to `TopicId2` component) you could render your component with the following code:

```
const topicsMap = {
    topicId1: TopicId1,
    topicId2: TopicId2
};
const Topic = ({ match }) => {
    const TopicId = topicsMap[match.params.topicId] || TopicIdDefault;

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
            <TopicId />
            <CompanyDashboardMain/>
            <CompanyAccDetailsMain/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Note that I am defining a default component `TopicIdDefault` just in case the `match.params.topicId` does not match any of the expected values (*topicId1* and *topicId2*).

Comment: match.params.topicId is actually part of the Routing as shown here <Route path="/CompanyDashboard/:topicId" component={Topic} /> :topicid is the same name as my Component. Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: import CompanyAccDetails from './Components/Company/CompanyAccDetails'

Comment: So :topicid is actually CompanyAccDetails which is what Im trying to use as the Component Name

Comment: My code is based on this Codepen. The children of Topics needs to load a Component based on the breadcrumb/path name. https://codepen.io/stelco74/pen/qzdRxG

Comment: @StevenCollins, I don't get what you are trying to achieve. Would you care to edit your original question to add all the relevant code and information?

Comment: Have added my complete code for App.js and updated original post.  Thanks for your help im fairly new to React.